# Something in-between an audible separation between two syllables or two syllables and a diphthong in Spanish

Tags: pronunciación

There are words that have something in-between an audible separation between two syllables or two syllables and a diphthong.

For example, the brē part of the Classical Latin word celebrētur, which sounds like the word ballet, but unlike a native English speaker saying the word ballet, there isn't an audible separation between the two syllables, and at the same time, unlike the words bell and lay, the brē part of the Classical Latin word celebrētur it isn't a diphthong ether, it's something in-between an audible separation between two syllables or two syllables and a diphthong, the brēs part of the Classical Latin words Septembrēs and Novembrēs sounds like the word blaze, but unlike the word blaze, it isn't a diphthong. It doesn't sound like brēs is a two-syllable word, nor does it sound like a diphthong but something in-between an audible separation between two syllables or two syllables and a diphthong, and the bri part of the Classical Latin word Novembribus sound like the bre part of the word breach, but unlike the word breach, it isn't a diphthong. It doesn't sound like bri is a two-syllable word, nor does it sound like a diphthong but something in-between an audible separation between two syllables or two syllables and a diphthong.

The recordings of the Classical Latin words celebrētur at 0:17, and Septembrēs at 1:15 in the first recording, Novembrēs at 7:23 and Novembribus at 8:48 in the second recording are by Thomas Bervoets:

- https://www.stilus.nl/ce-geluid/PlinMinEp-VI-16.htm
- https://www.stilus.nl/catilina/CicCatPrima.htm

I've heard that in Classical Latin, this is called a vowel hiatus.

Spanish also has words that have bres as well as bre. The recording of a Spanish word that has bres is by Manuel Bernal and a recording of a phrase that has the word hombre is by Covarrubias:

- https://archive.org/details/lp_romancero-de-la-via-dolorosa_manuel-bernal
- https://forvo.com/word/en_el_primer_d%C3%ADa%2C_el_hombre_cre%C3%B3_a_dios._%28an%C3%B3nimo%29/

Is the Spanish example, which is the same as brēs in Classical Latin called vowel hiatus too or is it called something else?

Classical Latin evolved into Vulgar Latin which evolved into the Romance Languages including Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

En español como en latín también existe la figura del "**hiato**", en este sentido, existen varios tipos de hiato, el "**Hiato acentual**", el "**Hiato vocálico simple**" y el "**Hiato vocálico de repetición de sonido**".

> In Spanish as in Latin there is also the figure of the "**hiato**", in
> this sense, there are several types of hiatus, the "**Hiato
> acentual**", the "**Hiato vocálico simple**" and the "**Hiato vocálico
> de repetición de sonido**". (**Accentual hiatus**", "**Simple vowel
> hiatus**", "**Sound repetition vowel hiatus**")

*Cuando la letra H aparece entre dos vocales, no interfiere en la formación de hiatos ni diptongos. En los hiatos, la palabra se divide de igual modo y la H permanece unida a la segunda vocal. Por ejemplo: al-co-hol, bú-ho, re-hén.*

100 Ejemplos de Hiato

Fuente: https://www.ejemplos.co/hiato/

---

**Hiato RAE** (Real Academia de la Lengua Española Española)

> **hiato.** 1. Es la secuencia de dos vocales que se pronuncian en sílabas
> distintas: grú - a, pa - ís, ca - er, dis - cu - tí - ais. Desde el
> punto de vista fonético, son hiatos las combinaciones de vocal abierta
> (a, e, o) átona + vocal cerrada (i, u) tónica: raíz, laúd, reír,
> transeúnte, oír; de vocal cerrada tónica + vocal abierta átona: María,
> ríe, frío, cacatúa, acentúe, búho; de dos vocales iguales: azahar,
> poseer, chiita, alcohol; y de dos vocales abiertas distintas: caer,
> aorta, teatro, etéreo, coágulo, poeta (aunque, en el habla, la
> secuencia de dos vocales abiertas —especialmente cuando ninguna de
> ellas es tónica— puede articularse como diptongo, esta combinación
> vocálica se considera siempre hiato desde el punto de vista
> normativo).
>
> 2. Las otras combinaciones posibles de dos vocales (salvo la secuencia de una vocal abierta tónica seguida de una cerrada átona, que forma
>    siempre diptongo en español) se pueden pronunciar como hiatos o como
>    diptongos (→ diptongo, 1 y 2), dependiendo de diversos factores: las
>    palabras concretas en las que se encuentren incluidas, el origen
>    geográfico o social del hablante (→ 4 y 5), el mayor o menor esmero en
>    la pronunciación, etc. Dada esta variabilidad, se ha optado por
>    establecer una serie de convenciones sobre qué ha de considerarse
>    diptongo y qué ha de considerarse hiato a la hora de acentuar
>    gráficamente las palabras; así, las secuencias vocálicas distintas de
>    las descritas en el primer párrafo se considerarán siempre diptongos a
>    efectos de acentuación gráfica (→ tilde2, 2.1.1 y 2.2.1).
> 3. La h intercalada no influye en absoluto en la consideración como diptongo o como hiato de una secuencia vocálica; así, hay grupos de
>    vocales con h intermedia que forman diptongo: ahijado, ahumar,
>    prohibir, y otros que forman hiato: ahínco, turbohélice, prohíbe.
> 4. Tanto en España como en América existe una tendencia antihiática muy marcada en el habla popular, lo que provoca que determinadas
>    secuencias vocálicas que son hiatos en el habla culta se pronuncien
>    como diptongos entre hablantes poco instruidos, con el consiguiente
>    cierre en el timbre de la vocal átona; así, en el habla esmerada,
>    deben evitarse pronunciaciones como [golpiár] por golpear, [akordión]
>    por acordeón, [kuéte] por cohete, [pelié] por peleé, etc. No obstante,
>    en algunos países de América, particularmente en México, este cierre
>    vocálico se da también en el nivel culto.
> 5. En amplias zonas de América es muy frecuente que se pronuncien como diptongos secuencias formadas por una vocal cerrada átona y una vocal
>    abierta tónica, o por dos vocales cerradas distintas; estas mismas
>    secuencias, por el contrario, se pronuncian mayoritariamente como
>    hiatos en el español de España y de algunos países americanos, por
>    ejemplo, la Argentina o el Ecuador. Así, en España y parte de América,
>    la palabra guion se pronuncia como bisílaba ([gi - ón]), debido al
>    hiato, mientras que en otras áreas americanas se pronuncia como
>    monosílaba ([gión]), debido al diptongo; lo mismo sucede con jesuita,
>    que vacila, según las zonas, entre el hiato ([je - su - í - ta]) y el
>    diptongo ([je - suí - ta]). Sobre la acentuación gráfica de las
>    palabras que incluyen estas combinaciones vocálicas, → tilde2, 2.1.

Hiato

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

https://www.rae.es/dpd/hiato